# weblogic: Determine how must process time to writing logs

Tags: java, linux, weblogic

I am trying to figure out how much time a weblogic instance is taking writing logs from the application deployed to it.

Top doesn't show any I/O, it there some way via mission control / jra recording / heap dump to see that info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the shell, you can use `iotop` command. You may need to install it.